# Add records in WebAPI via iCollection Model?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

In a WebAPI POST controller, with EntityFramework, i want to add some new records, based on a ICollection.

So, i have a Model of Products. This Model has a reference (ICollection) to Model Colors.
I have a POST Controller that should be able to add one or more Colors, bound to the Product.

I have the below code:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostProduct(string InternalReferenceId, int SupplierId, Colors colors)
        {
            Product dbProduct = db.Products.FirstOrDefault(s => s.InternalReferenceId == InternalReferenceId && s.SupplierId == SupplierId);

            if (dbProduct != null)
            {
        // iCollection
                dbProduct.Colors = colors;
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Ok();
}
```

The JSON could look like this;

```
{
    "color": "white"
},
{
    "color": "black"
},
{
    "color": "green"
}
```

Any ideas as to how i assign `dbProduct.Colors` to the content/model of colors, which is JSON?

Comment: What is the type of dbProduct.Colors? Surely this should just be a mapping exercise between your API type and the EF type? And your colors parameter looks like it should be an array/collection. i.e. Color[] colors...

Comment: dbProduct.Colors is a iCollection<Color>. This is the definition in the Model: public virtual ICollection<Color> Colors { get; set; }

The JSON is just a simple example. I holds more values than just "color".

Comment: This is the error that VS shows: Cannot convert source type 'Models.Color' to target type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<Models.Color>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to assign a single item (`Models.Color`) to a collection (`ICollection<Models.Color>`). Thus you need to change your API to accept a collection of `Models.Color`:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostProduct(string InternalReferenceId, int SupplierId, ICollection<Color> colors)
```

Comment: That gives me the following error: Cannot convert type IEnumerable<..> to ICollection<...> ?

Comment: Oops, should have been ICollection<Color>. Have amended answer accordingly.